# I consider if I should delete a /load.php?lang= URL resource and I don't know if it would cause a problem

Tags: php, mediawiki, language, query-string

I have an Hebrew 1.35.1 all-core MediaWiki website; generally I have no significant performance problems reported in Google Page Speed insights with that website besides one problem which occurs in the following three different contexts:

- **Enable text compression:** `/load.php?lang=`
- **Remove unused JavaScript:** `/load.php?lang=`
- **Eliminate render-blocking Resources:** `/load.php?lang=`
- I believe this has to do with my site being Hebrew-interfaced (from installation onwards).

If I find a way to remove this query string from domains, should this cause any problem to my website? (Language/SEO/whatever)?

Comment: Core skin is TimeLess.